# Brackets config not valid JSON?

Tags: json, adobe-brackets

I'm using the latest version of Adobe Brackets for macOS and can't seem to get a config working.

Even if I take the defaultPreferences.json and simply copy it to my own brackets.json file I get an error upon loading Brackets saying that it is not valid JSON.

Here is my config: https://pastr.io/view/rBxYg3kffvJ - can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: `// Preferences for Language Tools
 "languageTools":
 },` looks wrong to me

Comment: Fixed that but there are still issues.

Comment: All right, yes, the file seems to have multiple issues. Is anything stopping you from fixing them? If you've fixed something, I recommend updating it to reflect your current json, otherwise it's a waste of time to be identifying issues you've already dealt with.

Comment: This is what I have now: https://pastr.io/view/gX9MHOnswU3